# Message sent to slack channel using python script is not properly aligned

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

I am trying to send a message to a Slack channel using a python script. The message gets delivered to the slack channel however I see the formatting of the next is not correct.

Given below is my Dataframe but when this get sent to the slack channel the text is not properly aligned.

```
name, sales_prct,return_prct
product_id_1234567, 45%, 2%
product_id_45764333, 65%, 12%
product_id_675335, 42%, 7%
```

Comment: Use "\```" (tripple backquote) at start and end of the text. For example: \```this is text.\```

Comment: @Kaushal28 thanks for responding. I am using a f string as below

`message = f'''Hello, given below is the summary {df}'''`

Comment: You are using that in python so it's a python multiline string but it won't be sent like that in your slack channel. Try this: `message = f"Hello, given below is the summary \```{df}\```"`. Also, what you are using is triple single quotes and not backquotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To format the text in slack we are supposed to use triple backquotes "```" before and after the text. So you can format your string in python as follows:

````
message = f"Hello, given below is the summary ```{df}```"
````